# How to suppress the window scrollbar and avail the space used for the same

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml

In the page I'm working there are 2 divs vertically. Now I want to show the upper div always to the user and there would be scrollbar for the 2nd div (having a fixed height) as the content grows. Now the problem is at the right of this forced scrollbar for the 2nd div there is some space left for the normal scrollbar of the browser. Can i suprees this normal scrollbar so that the scroolbar for the 2nd div mimic the normal one. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Specify `body {overflow-y:hidden}` in your CSS.

Note that this won't work for IE6, where the vertical scrollbar is always there.